# Reload JavaScript files without refreshing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've a HTML which loads several Javascript files:

```
<script src="assets/js/a.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/b.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As I debug/test my Javascripts in my browser's console, is it possible to reload these Javascript files without the need to reload the entire HTML page?

Comment: If you're debugging, you want to debug what the user experiences. If you just reload a script, you're starting from a different context then a user would. So reloading the entire HTML while debugging isn't such a bad thing.

Comment: good question. but it has already been asked and answered. [Is there a way to refresh just the javascript include while doing development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285006/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-just-the-javascript-include-while-doing-development)

Comment: thanks for all the answers and comments.

Comment: I think the problem during debugging is even worse: reloading the HTML using Ctrl+F5 fails to reload any of the asset files, such as .JS files, which may have changed.

Answer (score 19):

You could remove and then re-add them:

```
$('script').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') !== 'assets/js/jquery.min.js') {
        var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', '');
        setTimeout(function(){ $(this).attr('src', old_src + '?'+new Date()); }, 250);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Truth - he has a jquery script element in the question code!

Comment: +1 to negate that -1. @Truth: 3 doesn't means all :) atleast at StackOverflow :) but PitaJ your code is buggy. 1. setTimeout wont does nothing in this code. 2. more importantly, replacing script wont work here. you can only add a new script [Replacing script src using jquery not executed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2226519/17447)

Comment: I think you mean Date.now() instead of new Date()

Answer (score 2):

Nope (at least not without a hack), in fact - be very careful reloading so much. It's quite possible that your javascripts become cached, which leads to many-a-headache trying to debug, since your updates are not applying.

https://superuser.com/questions/36106/force-refreshing-only-javascript-files-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: You can always reload with Ctrl+F5, which will refresh the cache

Answer (score 1):

Based on PitaJ's solution.

Reload all javascript in a function. You can call this from anywhere you want.

```
 $('script').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src') != undefined && $(this).attr('src').lastIndexOf('jquery') == -1) {
            var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
            var that = $(this);
            $(this).attr('src', '');

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.attr('src', old_src + '?' + new Date().getTime());
            }, 250);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with jQuery 2.0.3 and chrome 43

```
 function reloadScript(id) {

    var $el =  $('#' + id);

    $('#' + id).replaceWith('<script id="' + id + '" src="' + $el.prop('src') + '"><\/script>');
}
```

Chrome is complaining, but works:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Your script tag has to have id. 
Call in console:

```
reloadScript('yourid');
```

Does not remove event listeners, so for for example button click gets executed twice if once reloaded.