# How can I reload modified .js files from the browser console?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, console, requirejs

Can I use RequireJS 2 to reload a recently updated .js file? Here is my use case:

1. I have a *Backbone.js* object called *Foo* with the function *Bar* that simply does `alert("abc")`;
2. In a webpage, I somehow call `Foo.Bar()` and get an alert thing with "abc"
3. In my text editor, I change that function's definition to do instead `alert("def")`
4. In the same webpage, I open the console and run some update function
5. When I call again `Foo.Bar()`, I get the alert with "def"

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload JavaScript files without refreshing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868277/reload-javascript-files-without-refreshing-html)

Answer (score 5):

You can acess the chome console by pressing: Ctrl+Shift+J And going to the "Console" Tab.
There Type the following:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "Path to Js File";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

It should update the JavaScript file without reloading the whole page.

> - Path to file Could be: 
>   1) http/s://yourdomain.com/path/jsfile.js 
>   2) file://path/jsfile.js - (Local file system)

*Note:

The method used above does not require the RequireJS Library.*

Comment: this method actually doesn't work with requirejs, it's only good for global space libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to (load AND refresh) the js file, I suggest to define a function in your base javascript file like

```
function reloadJS(file) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "/" + file + ".js";
  myWindow = window.open(script.src + "?v=" + Math.random());
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  myWindow.close();
 }
```

and call it from console like **reloadJS("myjsfilename")**

this will reload the js file and force it to update the file for browser.